# trying to select from a combobox in javascript but usual way doesnt work

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to select on of those option using this line

```
document.getElementById("combobox-month").selectedIndex = 5;
```

But it wont work any idea why?

```js
document.getElementById("combobox-month").selectedIndex = 5;
```

```html
<div id="content-birthday">
  <div id="combobox-month" class="combobox-wrapper">
    <select name="bday_month">
      <option value="1">January</option>
      <option value="2">February</option>
      <option value="3">March</option>
      <option value="4">April</option>
      <option value="5">May</option>
      <option value="6">June</option>
      <option value="7">July</option>
      <option value="8">August</option>
      <option value="9">September</option>
      <option value="10">October</option>
      <option value="11">November</option>
      <option value="12">December</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can someone explain me why this is said to be off topic? this is a really good question as theres a very unique way to get the value out of this while for the other sort of value field its strait forward and simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you used the wrong selector.

```js
document.querySelector("select").selectedIndex = 5;
```

If you want to use a class instead then add to select a class like "select-month".

```js
document.querySelector(".select-month").selectedIndex = 5;
```

The `.` is really important. It indicates that the following string is a class.
`#` stands for id

Answer (score 1):

`combobox-month` is the *id* of the parent div of the *select* element. You should target the *select* element. You can use [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) which allows CSS like selector.

Try

```js
document.querySelector("select[name=bday_month]").selectedIndex = 5;
```

```html
<div id="content-birthday">
  <div id="combobox-month" class="combobox-wrapper">
    <select name="bday_month">
      <option value="1">January</option>
      <option value="2">February</option>
      <option value="3">March</option>
      <option value="4">April</option>
      <option value="5">May</option>
      <option value="6">June</option>
      <option value="7">July</option>
      <option value="8">August</option>
      <option value="9">September</option>
      <option value="10">October</option>
      <option value="11">November</option>
      <option value="12">December</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Targeted Element was wrong.you are targeted the parent of select so Add some id  to the select tag element.Then call via dom

```js
document.getElementById("select").selectedIndex = 5;
```

```html
<div id="content-birthday">
  <div id="combobox-month" class="combobox-wrapper">
    <select name="bday_month" id="select">
      <option value="1">January</option>
      <option value="2">February</option>
      <option value="3">March</option>
      <option value="4">April</option>
      <option value="5">May</option>
      <option value="6">June</option>
      <option value="7">July</option>
      <option value="8">August</option>
      <option value="9">September</option>
      <option value="10">October</option>
      <option value="11">November</option>
      <option value="12">December</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the div element, not the combobox that way.

Put an id on the combobox and use that in yout getElementById.

Answer (score 0):

Please specify the id to a dropdown.`combobox-month` is the id of a div

```
document.getElementById("bday_month").selectedIndex = 5;
```

Added bday_month as th id.

```
 <select id="bday_month" name="bday_month">
  <option value="1">January</option>
  <option value="2">February</option>
  <option value="3">March</option>
  <option value="4">April</option>
  <option value="5">May</option>
  <option value="6">June</option>
  <option value="7">July</option>
  <option value="8">August</option>
  <option value="9">September</option>
  <option value="10">October</option>
  <option value="11">November</option>
  <option value="12">December</option>
</select>
```